# Is add-ttmwebsite a mandatory step for publishing the content

Tags: topology-manager

In Tridion Sites 9.0, I need to publish content to the broker database and then the same content would be retrieved via APIs based on the publications Ids. As such the publications do not have a website associated with it as it is for a mobile app. But as per the Topology setup, It needs to have a website, web application, and mapping (of a web application, Publication, and environment-purpose, created via add-ttmmapping) even for publishing the content.

Is there any way to set up publishing without the need for a website and web app set up? One can surely set these additional logical units, i.e. website, web app, etc. but is that the optimal way if it is not associated with a website.

I saw that the same query was asked earlier but that was in context of SDL web 8.5, so I am asking again in case there are possibilities to do set ups in sites 9 without the need of add-ttmwebsite.

Comment: if you are using the new publishing framework with topology manager then yes it's mandatory to Add-TtmWebsite and Add-TtmMapping

Comment: possibilities to do set-ups in sites 9 without the need of add-ttmwebsite? why you looking for this? what is blocking you here from setting up add-ttmwebsite baseURR and mapping?

Comment: setting up an add-website doesn't mandatory to run a website app for a mobile app. it's up to your implementation how you are accessing the content out using API. In the DXA framework, OOTB content providers have that localization URL check. if you are using your own rest service with Graphql API queries to provide the content for the mobile app. then go for it. just add website and mapping in Topology for publishing.

Comment: Thanks Velmurugan for the responses. I understand that adding website using add-ttmwebsite is necessary in topology set up.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the new publishing framework with topology manager then yes, it's mandatory to **Add-TtmWebsite** and **Add-TtmMapping**.

Setting up an add-website doesn't mandatory to run a web app for a mobile app. It's up to your implementation how you are accessing the content out using API. In the DXA framework, OOTB content providers have that localization URL check. If you are using your own REST service with GraphQL API queries to provide the content for the mobile app, then go for it. Just add the website and mapping in Topology for publishing.